# Problem with Webview app

Tags: android, eclipse, webview

I'm just started looking at developing apps. I have made some of the tutorials (HelloWorld), but when I try to make a WebView app following the tutorial for that it won't work. Each time I run the app on my phone I get the "Force Close". I use eclipse. I'm sorry that i cannot be more specific - but my point is that my knowledge doesn't go further than failing in a tutorial.

Because of me huge lack of knowledge about developing I would be grateful if anyone would like to help me developing an app for android phones, using webview to show www.lectio.dk.

Christian.

Comment: There should be a "LogCat" window in your development tool showing some error, providing the error will get you some useful anwsers, asking someone to develop the app for you (without remuneration) will not.

Answer (score 0):

If you're specifying Android 2.3 as the Target Name, the WebView example won't work in the emulator.  See  http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12987.  A workaround is to specify Android 2.2.